# Locking game update speed causing high CPU usage. How do I make thread sleep when not doing anything?

Tags: java

So I'm currently just learning how to do this, and someone said that the code is inefficient because the thread is still running when nothing is updating. When I look at the CPU usage in the task manager, it shoots up to 35 - 45% and 20 in the CPU column when only a black screen is being rendered. Is there a way to make the thread sleep when the CPU isn't updating anything?

Thanks!

```
public void run() {

    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;         
    double delta = 0;

    int frames = 0;
    int updates = 0;

    while (running) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while(delta >= 1) {
            update();
            updates++;
            delta--;
        }

        render();
        frames++;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
            timer += 1000;
            updates = 0;
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
    stop(); 
}
```

Comment: You make a thread sleep when not updating anything by having it be event-driven vs simply sitting in a tight loop.

Comment: Calculate the difference between the tim it took to render/update the frame and the amount of time you might need to sleep (ie about 16 milliseconds for 60fps) then sleep (via `Thread.sleep`) for the difference...

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The only good way of doing it, is to execute the `yourThread.wait()` when the game stops doing stuff, and then `yourThread.notify()` when the game makes an action again.

Comment: @Acecle Np, glad if this helps. Also don't forget to mark this question as "accepted" if it helps

Comment: That's not what `.start()` does. It's used only to start the thread the first time, not to break a call to `sleep()`.

Comment: @DanGetz oops, My bad! Ill fix it

Comment: This is just wrong. You shouldn't write answers if you don't understand the subject matter.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't render on your own threads. SWING is thread unsafe so all GUI operations should happen on the SWING thread. It just happens SWING has a thread specially made for this.

```
timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000 / 60, this);
timer.start();


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Do your stuff (ignore 'e')
}
```

Comment: Since the OP has not mentioned what framework they are using, this makes a better comment then an answer

Comment: Since I see `render()` and 60 (fps), and with the code style, it's an educated guess.

Comment: But it's still only a "guess" - render could be using a `BufferedStrategy` or even some other framework...better to ask clarification avoid the potential down votes ;)

Comment: For reference, this looks suspiciously similar to the OP's code http://stackoverflow.com/q/25167305